# Set dynamic id as post body

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have to send a JSON body similar to this to the API:

```
"users": {
    "{id}": {
        "someProperty": "This is some text"
    }
}
```

Where `{id}` is a dynamic id that I must set before sending the request. (fe. "1", "2", ...)

How can I define a GSON object for this?

```
data class Test(
    @SerializedName("users")
    val users: Users
)

data class Users(
    // WHAT TO WRITE HERE?
)
```

I was thinking on using `Map` but I don't know if it's the right way

```
data class Test(
    @SerializedName("users")
    val users: Map<String, User>
)

data class User(
    @SerializedName("someProperty")
    val someProperty: String
)
```

Comment: not relevant to your question, but you don't need `@SerializedName` if your variable name is the same as what you would put in the annotation, ie: `@SerializedName("users")  val users: Users`

Comment: Yep, this is totally fine. (I would recommend keeping `@SerializedName` retained there, so that: 1) you declare/bind the JSON property names making your class fields be able to have arbitrary field names in case of necessity; 2) visually you can see the class is designed for data transfer.)